# How to deploy Spring Boot Application to Docker?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

So, the image I uploaded to the conter does not display.

Here are the steps I took, and I'll add right away that I used gradle.

1. I downloaded the Docker plugin to IntelliJ
2. I created a Dockerfile in which I put:

3. In the terminal, I typed the following commands to build the project:
4. Then I typed (to create an image and display it):
5. And here is where the problem arises, I entered the following commands:

   (I want to run on port `8081` because my app listens on port `8080`. I don't know if it matters but that's how I did it)

I display the list using command:  `docker container ps`

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong that it's not working, where I'm making a mistake. Is there something else I should do? In general, the spring boot application at this time should be running? What does it look like, I read some tutorials but unfortunately nothing helped, and I was doing the same way as them

Comment: When you build the image, do you pass a `--build-arg JAR_FILE=...` option?

Comment: It's not your immediate problem, but if your application listens on port 8080, then the second `docker run -p` port needs to be port 8080 as well.  The first number can be anything that's not otherwise in use on your host.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, when building the application this parameter is passed. And as for the second statement, that is, if my application listens on port 8080 then the docker created must also listen on it? btw: I changed the port, but it still doesn't work, but I'll keep it in mind, thanks for the tip

Comment: The second `docker run -p` port number needs to match the port number the program inside the container is listening on.  The program also must be listening on the special 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" address (not 127.0.0.1 "unreachable from outside the current container").  The two `docker run -p` ports can be different.

Comment: your commands & dockerfile got lost

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a Docker image with Maven plugin by defining in pom.xml and run 'mvn install':

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <name>
                            ${project.groupId}/twitter.to.kafka.service:${project.version}
                        </name>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Create Docker image during mvn install -->
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <!-- Spring Boot use the Layered approach : to prevent creating a single fat jar, and use caching during image update -->
                            <goal>
                                build-image
                            </goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Can you try this instead of manually creating a Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 0):

try to run:

```
docker run -p 8081:8081 springreadyapp
```

i add a link to my repo which explain about that, in maven [docker with spring](https://github.com/netanelshriki/docker-with-spring)

Answer (score 0):

A less laborious solution is using [Jib](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib) under GoogleContainerTools. It is available as a Gradle plugin.

> Jib builds optimized Docker and OCI images for your Java applications
> without a Docker daemon - and without deep mastery of Docker
> best-practices.

There are alternative options, here are the **steps for using Jib Gradle plugin to build a container image and run it**:

1. Add the jib plugin to `build.gradle`:

   ```
   plugins {
     id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '3.2.1'
   }
   ```
2. Customize the image build in `build.gradle`:

   Since your app listens on port 8080, the 8080 port on the container will need to be exposed

   ```
    jib.from {
        image = <YOUR BASE IMAGE>
    }
    jib.container {
        entrypoint = <YOUR CONTAINER ENTRY POINT>
        ports = <EXPOSED CONTAINER PORTS. Eg: ['8080']>
    }
    jib.to{
        image = <OUTPUT IMAGE. Eg: myapp:latest>
    }
   ```
3. Build image from the command line:

   Open a command line under the root of your project

   3.1. Build image tarball:

   ```
   gradle jibBuildTar
   ```

   This builds and saves your image to `build/jib-image.tar`

   3.2. Load the image tarball into docker:

   ```
   docker load --input build/jib-image.tar
   ```
4. Run image as a container from the command line:

   ```
   docker run <OUPUT IMAGE> -p <HOST PORT>:<EXPOSED CONTAINER PORT>
   ```

   Eg:

   ```
   docker run myapp -p 8081:8080
   ```

   Here, the 8080 port on the container is mapped to the 8081 port on the host (You can also map it to the 8080 port on the host if you want, the container has its own IP address separate from the host).

More details can be found in the [jib-gradle-plugin Quickstart](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin)